# ConfigureAwait on a call which is already running on a threadpool thread?

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a WPF application (and therefore a synchronization context). In my async calls on the UI thread I use `ConfigureAwait(false)` to continue on a background thread. That part I fully understand.

However, once on a background thread, is `ConfigureAwait(false)` required for all following calls?

```cs
public async void SomeMouseClick(someArgs)
{
    await OnTheBackground().ConfigureAwait(false);
}

public async Task OnTheBackground()
{
    await someClient.Execute();
    // am I on the UI thread now, or on still on a thread pool thread?
}
```

Comment: The `ConfigureAwait()` only affects the continuation, so your call to `OnTheBackground()` is called from the context of the calling thread - a new thread is NOT created at that point. After the await for `OnTheBackground()` completes, the continuation MAY be on a new thread - but if nothing in `OnTheBackground()` blocked it may still continue on the calling thread. So you have to be careful about doing compute-bound stuff, even in an `async` method.

Comment: Let's assume that `await someClient.Execute();` uses a socket (and therefore IOCP) and there is nothing in the internal socket buffer, so it can't complete directly.

If I understand you correctly, the `OnTheBackground` call will continue on the UI thread since there was no continuation in `SomeMouseClick` and the call to `someClient.Execute` did not configure where the continuation should continue?

Comment: That's correct. You can check this by putting `Debug.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);` in various places to see what threads things are running on. Note that after the await for `OnTheBackground()` in `SomeMouseClick()` is completed, it WILL be running on a different thread (assuming `await someClient.Execute();` resumed on a different thread).

Comment: Add that to an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ConfigureAwait()` only affects the continuation, so your call to `OnTheBackground()` is called from the context of the calling thread - a new thread is NOT created at that point.

After the await for `OnTheBackground()` completes, the continuation MAY be on a new thread - but if nothing in `OnTheBackground()` blocked it may still continue on the calling thread. So you have to be careful about doing compute-bound stuff, even in an async method!

This is best illustrated with an example. Consider the following code for a WPF application with a single button called `Button` with its click event handled by a `Button_Click()` method:

```
bool firstTime = true;

private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Button_Click() called on thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    await OnTheBackground().ConfigureAwait(false);

    Debug.WriteLine("Button_Click() continued on thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
}

public async Task OnTheBackground()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("OnTheBackground() called on thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    if (firstTime)
        await Task.Delay(0);
    else
        await Task.Delay(10);

    firstTime = false;

    Debug.WriteLine("OnTheBackground() continued on thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
}
```

When you click the button the first time, it will wind up calling `await Task.Delay(0);` inside `OnTheBackground()`. Because this does not need to block, when the `await Task.Delay(0)` returns, it continues on the same thread that called it.

Then when this returns to `Button_Click()`, even though the await in there has `.ConfigureAwait(false)` it will continue on the original UI thread, because nothing that it called has transitioned to a different thread.

Thus, on first press of the button the output in the debug window is something like:

```
Button_Click() called on thread 1
OnTheBackground() called on thread 1
OnTheBackground() continued on thread 1
Button_Click() continued on thread 1
```

Everything is on the same thread, as expected.

However, on second press of the button it ends up calling `await Task.Delay(10);` which *will* cause the await to return on a new thread, since `Task.Delay(10)` will block.

So when it gets back to `await OnTheBackground().ConfigureAwait(false);`, it will NOT continue on the UI thread, but rather continues on a different thread.

Thus on the second press of the button, the debug output is something like:

```
Button_Click() called on thread 1
OnTheBackground() called on thread 1
OnTheBackground() continued on thread 1
Button_Click() continued on thread 4
```

In this case, you can see that the code after the `await` in `Button_Click()` is now running on a non-UI thread.

Comment: Wouldn't the output from the second click be  
`Button_Click() called on thread 1`  
`OnTheBackground() called on thread 1`  
`OnTheBackground() continued on thread 4`  
`Button_Click() continued on thread 4`  ?

Comment: @MichaelGehling Nope - the call to `await Task.Delay(10);` lacks a `.ConfigureAwait(false)` so it will continue on the context from which it was called. (You can verify this by running the sample code and inspecting the output in the debugger.) I actually copy-pasted these results from the Debug window to avoid errors! ;)

Comment: @MichaelGehling Although you may reasonably wonder why, even though `OnTheBackground()` continued on the UI thread, the call to `await OnTheBackground().ConfigureAwait(false);` continues on a different thread. That's how the state machines generated by `async/await` end up managing things. There's a lot of information about this in [Jon Skeet's "eduasync"](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/eduasync/) blog (scroll to the very end for the start of the articles)

Comment: ok, I tried it and you are right... I expected the configureAwait(false) to take effect down the call tree, so that the Task.Delay(10) would be allowed to continue on another thread. So if I want all subsequent awaits to be allowed to continue on another thread, I either have to put on each await call the configureAwait(false) or I have to remove the SynchronizationContext at the beginning and reset it afterwards, right?

Comment: @MichaelGehling There's some discussion about this in the [Microsoft async/await best practices guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming). It boils down to: "Use `.ConfigureAwait(false)` where you can, especially in library code". Generally the only places to avoid `.ConfigureAwait(false)` are in top-level code or UI code where you want to access UI components after an `await`.